# After video codec copy to mp4 format with ffmpeg,new video has no screen and has just audio

Tags: html, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have an issue.sometimes when I convert video to mp4 with codec copy,my created video in chrome just has audio and it's display a black screen, and in another browsers like firefox and internet explorer video doesn't play.
but I check this created video on my server and video displays.

And here is my code in below

```
ffmpeg -i -f mp4 -s 123.mov -codec copy 123.mp4
```

The Output Of ffprobe 123.mp4 is:

```
Metadata:major_brand:isom
minor_version :512
compatible_brands:isomiso2mp41
encoder:Lavf57.31.100
Duration: 00:26:58.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1334 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D)
,yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3],1200 kb/s, 29.97 fps,29.97 tbr, 30k tbn,29.97 tbc (default)
Metadata:handler_name: VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 12
7 kb/s (default)
Metadata:handler_name: SoundHandler
```

Comment: Could be due to the stream profile. What is the output of `ffprobe 123.mp4`?

Comment: wild guess - add a few switches .... -vcodec someAvailCodec -vf scale=640:480

Comment: @Mulvya The output of `fprobe 123.mp4` is

`Metadata:major_brand:isom
minor_version :512
compatible_brands:isomiso2mp41
encoder:Lavf57.31.100
Duration: 00:26:58.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1334 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D)
,yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3],1200 kb/s, 29.97 fps,29.97 tbr, 30k tbn,29.97 tbc (default)
Metadata:handler_name: VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 12
7 kb/s (default)
Metadata:handler_name: SoundHandler`

Comment: @RobertRowntree when I use as your mention it's ok.but I don't want change it,I want just to write it as mp4 with codec copy,because this command take few times on cpu time and it doesn't change quality of video.but I don't understand why some videos with different headers have this issue.

Comment: Your video is MPEG-4 Part-2 codec. For HTML5, you need MPEG-4 Part 10 (H.264 / AVC). You should convert it: `ffmpeg -i 123.mov -profile:v main -movflags +faststart 123.mp4 `

Comment: @Mulvya I create new video with your code and it's work fine on browsers.thank you.A question: Is there anyway for create it very fast like using `-codec copy` speed command?

Comment: You can use `-preset veryfast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gyan answer : My video is MPEG-4 Part-2 codec for HTML5, I need MPEG-4 Part 10 (H.264 / AVC). I must convert it like this: 
`ffmpeg -i 123.mov -profile:v main -movflags +faststart 123.mp4`